# dojo domconstruct.place gives error Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'appendChild'

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

usage domconstruct = http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/dom-construct.html#dojo-dom-construct-place

the second argument of place() is

refNode String|DomNode  The DOM node where the node should be placed. If a string, it is assumed to be the ID of the node

It says I can use DOM nodes, so I tried to get the domnode with jquery -> error
Also tried it with Dojo's query() -> same error

The error:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'appendChild'
```

My code
        domConstruct.place(errorBoxHtml, $("#"+currentView.id+" .content") , "first");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had the id, I would be able to type the id as a string in the function. That works fine. My div just had a classname, but I gave them all an id. Now I can just use the id as a string as 'refNode' argument in the function

Answer (score 1):

`dojo/query` and jQuery's selectors are not returning proper DOM nodes, but are returning a **list** of nodes.

You can see an example using jQuery on [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/wRQv3/). As you can see in the console, it says `"No it isn't"`, which means it isn't returning the DOM node of the selector you wrote, you can even see in the console what it actually returns (an array of DOM nodes).

I also made the same example using Dojo in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/wRQv3/1/). As you can see there, `dojo/query` doesn't return a DOM node either but a list of DOM nodes. However, when you use the `dojo/dom` module and the method `byId()` you will get a DOM node as a result.

This explains why your code doesn't work. If you're using a query, you can use `dojo/NodeList-dom` to get all nodes independently and call the function on each node, or if you're sure there's only 1 DOM node, you can also use:

```
require(["dojo/query", "dojo/domReady!"], function(query) {
    var myNode = query("...")[0];
});
```

But then I think something is wrong with the modules you're using. A query is used to retrieve zero to many results and you should use it that way. If you want to get a specific DOM node you should identify it by using ID's and use the `dojo/dom` module since it's made for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a chance that you are not getting a proper domNode (as Dojo understand it). Why don't you use the [dojo.byId](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/byId.html#dojo-byid) API to get it?